# Cura 5.2 beta, flat wall indentation

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing

Could anyone help me diagnose the setting or issue causing the effect in the second picture (indentation in a perfectly flat wall)?

The vertical wall should be flat, as shown in the first picture of the STL model.

[image: stl]

[image: G-code]

[image: view from other side]

[image: indentation going all the way around]

Comment: You need to show us which wall you are talking about. I see several walls that are not vertical.

Comment: If you compare the slice preview to the stl you will notice the indentation I'm talking about where it should be flat. If I still need to point it out, look at the bottom left of the image.

Comment: Have you checked that the stl is error free?

Comment: can you pull down to look *into* the affected layers?

Comment: Could you post the STL as a link or on e.g. Thingiverse? We can then try ourselves.

Comment: added some pictures, I cant post the model. 
Model comes from Autodesk Inventor STL export, I never had stl errors doing this. 
Indentation goes all the way around the pocket of what should be a perfectly flat wall.

Comment: Cura 5.2 is in Beta, have you tried a non beta release like e.g. 5.1.1? Also post a picture of the printed object, is the indentation present? Else it might be a drawing error, not an actual printing problem. This has happened in the past with Cura before if I remember correctly, I even think we have had a question on that before.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going off limited information here, if you could provide a full view of the model that would help.

That being said;
It looks like there is a feature on the opposite side of the wall "pulling" the lines towards the outside.
There is no direct setting to change to fix this, it looks like the layer size is limiting how close the printer can mimic the geometry.

Try dropping the layer height drastically (ie. .02 to .01) in order to see if the indentation changes it's shape.
Alternately, change the orientation to non-ideal angles and see what changes.

At the core, it seems your issue is the actual interpretation of the model by the slicing software and may not have a setting associated with it.

Comment: I added some pictures to my post. The indentation goes all the around that pocket. The slicer should be able to leave such a gap in the infill or inner wall instead of on the outer wall, or even vary with trace width to account for whatever is doing this.
I tried to reduce the wall count to 1 with no effect, I have 5 set for the slice preview. No effect with layer height changes.

Comment: Ok, lets dig into this some more then. Is this the latest Cura release (5.1)? Do you have access to standard CAD software (SolidWorks, Blender, ChituBox, Fusion, etc.)? Have you tried 0%, 1%, 5%, 95%, 99%, and 100% infill? You have quite the conundrum here, assuming you have all the above already done - I would say you want a complete rebuild, i.e. importing the mesh into a CAD program, converting the mesh to a solid, converting the solid back to a mesh/STL. If that doesn't work then I would assume it has to be a setting issue in Cura. If this file is publicly available, you should share it.